# Java program doesn't show swing elements until resized?

Tags: java, swing

Could anyone please explain why this may be happening?
 Image is here [Image](http://tinypic.com/r/2n39ep/6) I couldn't upload because I'm a new user.

```
setTitle("jNote");
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("jNote.png");
    setIconImage(icon);
```

Comment: Put pack() and setVisible(true) in the end of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually GUI size can be suggested by the contents.  If called after the components are added, `pack()` will cause the GUI to be the minimum size it needs to display them.

[image: jNote]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JNote {

    public JComponent getGui(int rows, int cols) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,2));

        p.add(new JLabel("1"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(rows, cols);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(
                ta,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        p.add(sp);
        p.add(
            new JLabel("Rows: " + rows + "    " + "Columns: " + cols),
            BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                int cols = 20;
                JNote jNote = new JNote();
                for (int rows=6; rows>0; rows-=2) { 
                    JFrame f = new JFrame("jNote " + rows + "x" + cols);
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                    f.add(jNote.getGui(rows, cols));

                    f.pack();
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for those constraints for BorderLayout and one very nice example :-) and one for providing one wonderful idea about the merits of using `setLocationByPlatform()` :-)

Comment: @brano88 : IMHO, when one uses `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, one simply wants to hide the JFrame and makes it available for `GARBAGE COLLECTION` though using `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, it's same as using `System.exit(0);`, where you are forcing the application to shutdown, deliberately.

Comment: +1 Thank you this fixed the problem. I was putting pack(); before I'd declared all the components.

Answer (score 3):

When setting dimensions via preferred sizes, you must call `pack()` in order to apply your preferred sizes.  Resizing a frame packs it as well, hence your observations.

```
// component initializations
yourFrame.pack();
```

Comment: I used pack and it made my window really small are there any arguments I need to add?

Comment: You will need to set your frame's preferred size as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you should do:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JordanOsborn extends JFrame{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();


    public JordanOsborn(){
        super("jNote");
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        add(panel);
        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("jNote.png");
        setIconImage(icon);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new JordanOsborn();
            }

        });
    }
}
```